# Elementary proof of 2.2 in Isaacs's Character Theory

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, representation-theory

The exercise 2.2 of Isaacs' Character Theory is stated as follows:

> (a) Let $\chi$ be a character of $G$. Show that $\chi(g)$ is afforded
> by  a representation $\mathfrak{X}$ of $G$ such that all entries of
> $\mathfrak{X}(g)$ for all $g\in G$ lie in some field
> $F\subseteq\mathbb{C}$ with $|F:Q|<\infty.$
>
> (b) Let $\varepsilon=e^{\frac{2\pi i}{n}}$, where $n=|G|$ and $\chi$ be
> a character of $G$. Let $\sigma$ be an automorphism of the field
> $\mathbb{Q}[\varepsilon]$ and define $\chi^\sigma$ by
> $\chi^\sigma(g)=\chi(g)^\sigma$. Show that $\chi^\sigma$ is a
> character of $G$.

I know that if I can prove (a), then (b) will follow easily. Moreover, I know (a) is true according to the "Brauer's splitting field theorem" which asserts $\mathbb{Q}[\varepsilon]$ is a splitting field of $G$. But this problem is in the second chapter of the book, the first chapter of the book is on Wedderburn's theory and the second chapter is on some basic facts of characters. So how can I show (a) in an elementary way?

Comment: You can use Lemma (2.15) in Isaacs' book: $\frak{X}$$(g)$ is similar to a diagnonal matrix, which entries are $n$-th roots of unity ($|G|=n$). By adjoining these to $\mathbb{Q}$, you will end up with a finite extension of the rationals. Doing this for all $g$, still leaves you with a finite extension of $\mathbb{Q}$, as $G$ is finite.

Comment: @NickyHekster But note that we can't find a matrix $P$ such that $P^{-1}\mathfrak{X}(g)P$ is diagnonal for all $g$.

Comment: True, that is why you work "$g$ by $g$", so not all at once. Maybe this was not clear, but you adjoin a set of roots of unity $n$ times.

Comment: @NickyHekster But in order to prove the proposition, we need to find a $P$ such that all entries of $P^{-1}\mathfrak{X}(g)P$ are in $F$ for all $g\in G$. How can you make sure this is true according to your proof?

Comment: @NickyHekster I am afraid that I am also unconvinced by your argument. If this argument was correct then you would have proved Brauer's theorem that ${\mathbb Q}(e^{2\pi i/n})$ is a splitting field of $G$, where $n$ is the exponent of $G$, but that result occurs much later in Isaac's book as Thm 10.3.#

Comment: But that concerns *irreducible* representations/characters ... and that is not required in the above question.

Comment: I don't understand your last comment - any representation of $G$ can be written over a splitting field for $G$. In any case, the problem remains with your argument that you have shown how to handle each individual elements of $G$, but not all of them simultaneously.

Answer (score 3):

I don't know whether this is the intended proof, but you could argue as follows. Near the beginning of the chapter, Isaacs remarks that the whole theory works equally well with the field ${\mathbb A}$ of algebraic numbers in place of ${\mathbb C}$.

So the number of irreducible representations of $G$ over ${\mathbb A}$ and ${\mathbb C}$ are the same, and equal to the number of conjugacy classes of $G$, and the sum of the squares of their degrees is equal to $|G|$.

So all irreducible representations over ${\mathbb A}$ remain irreducible over ${\mathbb C}$ because if not then the sum of the squares of their degrees would go down when you reduced. Hence any representation over ${\mathbb C}$ is equivalent to one over ${\mathbb A}$.

Then to prove the result, just adjoin to ${\mathbb Q}$ all entries occurring in all matrices in this representation.

Comment: How do you go from "same number of irreducible representations" to "irreducible representations over $\mathbb A$ stay irreducible over $\mathbb C$" ? I believe a better argument for that would be that the character remains unchanged, and there's a character-theoretic criterion for irreducibility (namely, that its norm is $1$). Then you get that irreducible representations stay so over $\mathbb C$, and the number argument gives you that it's all there is

Comment: If any of them were reducible over ${\mathbb C}$ then the sum of the squares of their degrees would go down below $|G|$ when you reduced them over ${\mathbb C}$.

Comment: That's another way to see it, indeed!

Comment: I don't really see how any of this depends on the concepts of absolute irreducibility or splitting fields, although they are of course related. The remark in Isaacs' book does not involve them. It just says everything that follows remains true if we replace ${\mathbb C}$ by ${\mathbb A}$.